# Regex IF/Then expression with required characters

Tags: regex, if-statement, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm quite new to regex and very much stuck with the following expression. I'm looking for a regex code that allows the following combinations:

```
AA1A 1AA
AA 12
A 12
A 1
```

Requirements:

- String can not start with a number
- Only capital letters (A-Z)
- 1 space is required at predetermined places (see above examples)
- Numbers 0-9 can be used

I am currently working on/with the following string

`([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z0-9]{1,4})([ ]{1})([0-9A-Z]{1,3})`

The issue with this one that it does not allow the `AA1A 1AA` string..

Any ideas?

Comment: Requirement 2 and 4 should then be combined? Also, [`AA1A 1AA` is matched](https://regex101.com/r/ev2nAt/1). Could you please precise/clarify what you need to achieve?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't? resolving fine in my test (I'm using regex buddy to develop regex's)

Comment: The issue is that it currently also allows `11 AB` and `11 A` as true, that shouldn't happen.. I'll try out regex buddy, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Why `11 AB` and `11 A` should not match? You have not provided a rule that would fail these strings.

Comment: Hi, very true! And that is the rule I am looking for. Because I have not found it yet...

Comment: To whoever voted to close this: if you think regex questions don't belong on SO and should be closed/deleted then you have a lot of work to do...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the spec, the examples, and the fact you want the first example even though there's a space before it, it seems you need a regex like this one:

```
^[ ]*([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,3})[ ]([A-Z0-9]{1,3})$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lvRRDF/1)

Note that the ^ and $ are added to the regex. But I have a premonition that you're using the regex in some tool or functionality that implicitly assumes the regex needs to match for the whole line. Because otherwise your original regex would have matched "AA1A 1AA" in the string " AA1A 1AA".
If that's the case, the ^ and $ should be redundant for your purpose and you can remove them.

Explain:

```
^ :     // Matches the beginning of the string
        // or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled. 

[ ]* :   // 0 or more spaces

[A-Z] : // an upper case ascii letter

[A-Z0-9]{0,3} : // between 0 and 3 upper case letters or digits

[ ] :   // A character class with a space. Which matches 1 space.   
        // You don't actually need to put a single character in a character class.
        // But here it's done to make the space stand out more.

[A-Z0-9]{1,3} : // Between 1 and 3 upper case letters or digits

$ :     // Matches the end of the string 
        // or the end of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled.
```

The space in the middle isn't put in a capture group `(...)`. Because what would be the purpose of that? It's not like one would validate later that the capture group indeed contains a space.

If you want to search for those in a longer string you can use word boundaries instead.

```
\b([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,3})[ ]([A-Z0-9]{1,3})\b
```

The \b is a word boundary, it indicates a transition between a word character [A-Za-z0-9_] and a non-word character.  It's usefull to make sure that your word characters are followed or procedeed by a space or the start or end of the line.

For example, if you have a string like "ABC DE", then the regex `/[A-Z]{2}/g` would match "AB" and "DE". But with a wordboundary `/\b[A-Z]{2}\b/g` it would only match "DE", and not a part of a word like "AB".

Answer (score 1):

You just have to refine you first group to handle both :

- Two letters (AA)
- Two letters and letters and digits (AA1A)

  /([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z0-9]{1,4})([ ]{1})([0-9A-Z]{1,3})/g

to

```
/([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2})([ ]{1})([0-9A-Z]{1,3})/g
```

The matches (in bold) changes from :

**AA1A 1AA

AA 12

11 AB

A 12

11 A

A 1**

to :

**AA1A 1AA

AA 12**
11 AB
**A 12**
11 A
**A 1**

(notice 11 AB and 11 A are note matched)